# fprintf stops printing into file partway

Tags: c, string

This is a part in my code which is used to save all the information to a text file which is then used to load into my program later. Somehow the `fprintf` never printed everything i needed it to and always stopped midway.

Code:

```
for(int frames=0;frames<MAX_FRAME;frames++)
{
    fprintf(saveFileStream,"frame=%d xOffset=%d yOffset=%d delay=%d\n",frames,frame[frames].offset[XPOS],frame[frames].offset[YPOS],frame[frames].delay);//saves frame properties
    for(int xPos=0;xPos<MAX_X_COORDINATE;xPos++)
    {
        for(int yPos=0;yPos<MAX_Y_COORDINATE;yPos++)
        {
            if(frame[frames].particle[xPos][yPos].p!=' ')//skips blank characters
            {
                fprintf(saveFileStream,"frame=%d xPos=%d yPos=%d particle=%c\n",frames,xPos,yPos,frame[frames].particle[xPos][yPos].p);//saves particles
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and when this code is executed, it prints:

```
frame=0 xOffset=0 yOffset=0 delay=200
frame=1 xOffset=0 yOffset=0 delay=200
frame=2 xOffset=0 yOffset=0 delay=200
frame=3 xOffset=0 yOffset=0 delay=200
frame=4 xOffset=0 yOffset=0 delay=200
frame=5 xOffset=0 yOffset=0 delay=200
frame=6 xOffset=0 yOffset=0 delay=200
frame=7 xOffset=0 yOffset=0 delay=200
frame=8 xOffset=0 yOffset=0 delay=200
frame=9 xOffset=0 yOffset=0 delay=200
.
.
.
frame=203 xOffset=0 yOffset=0 delay=200
frame=204 xOffset=0 yOffset=0 delay=200
frame=205 xOffset=0 yOffset=0 delay=200
frame=206 xOffset=0 yOffset=0 delay=200
frame=207 xOffset=0 yO
```

(`MAX_FRAME` is 256)

What confused me the most is that it didn't stop after a line, but stopped while printing `yOffset` at frame 207.

If i set `MAX_FRAME` to a smaller number, it still stops printing before the counter `frames` reaches it.

Comment: This looks like output buffering. Try to close the file or flush the file buffers, I guess after this you will see the "missed" data in your file.

Comment: So if i don't flush `saveFileStream`, where do the data go? Aren't they written into the file immediately?

Comment: When you `fclose(saveFileStream);` all remaining data is written. I suspect you have a problem filling your `frame` array of struct. You likely have less that 256 filled elements and are invoking *Undefined Behavior* attempting to access unintialized values (but that is all *Crystal Ball* guessing without a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: Thanks, `fclose` after the loops fixed the problem.